# Wrong display of text file created by C program when opened in Notepad

Tags: c, file, character-encoding, notepad

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void init(char*filename)
{
    FILE* f = fopen(filename,"w");
    fprintf(f,"%d ",8);
    fprintf(f,"%d ",6);
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i ++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 8; j ++)
        {
            fprintf(f,"%d ", rand()%6);
        }
    }    
    fclose(f);
}
int main()
{
    init("input.txt");
}
```

when I open file I see this:

```
*‸‶‵‵‴‴‵‴‰‰‴′‵‵‱″‱‵‱′″‰″‰′″‴‴″′′‵‵‰‵‰″‴‵‱‱‰‵″′″″′″‱‵‴‵′‴″″‱‵″‱‴‴‵′‰*
```

Why don't I see the values of `rand()%6` that were printed to this file??

I  use Dev-C++ 5.6.3 to run the program and save it with format .cpp, Open with Notepad

Comment: I could not replicate your issue. See https://repl.it/repls/FlawedRosybrownEngineering. We might need some more system details to find out why that is happening

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon but i use w, Values binary stored by wb ???

Comment: yep, i use dev-c to run this program

Comment: The mode `"w"` or `"wb"` will only make a difference in the line endings on systems that use CR+LF. The `fprintf` format `"%d"` will print the text representation of an `int` number. I cannot reproduce the problem either, I get numbers separated by spaces as expected.

Comment: @pastaleg when I `fprintf(f, "%c", ' ')` this error can be sloved.

Comment: The per mille and per thousand signs are U+2030 and U+2031 respectively. The  ASCII codes for space and the digits 0 and 1 are 0x20, 0x30 and 0x31. It appears that you are viewing a plain ASCII (or UTF-8, for that matter) file as UTF-16 file.

Comment: works fine for me: https://godbolt.org/z/uYLfx-

Comment: @Stack Please add all information to your question instead of writing comments. What program do you use to open the file?

Comment: I know this program can work with many compilers,  But dev-c will make the error. it works fine  if I use `rand()` and error with `rand()%6`

Comment: @Bodo yep, What is more infor you need? I use Dev-C++ 5.6.3, save the program with format .cpp

Comment: @MOehm That should be an answer. I’ve added my own answer to this effect now but if you want to write your own I’ll delete mine and upvote yours instead.

Comment: @Stack instead of opening your file use `cat thefilename` (Linux, Mac)  or `type thefilename` (Windows)

Comment: @Stack Please [edit] your question to add requested information instead of answering in comments. What program do you use to open the file `"input.txt"`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: That's okay. Your link is spot on.

Comment: @Bodo i use notpad, and i think notepad misunderstood this file is UTF-16 encoded

Comment: @Stack You don't have to explain what others already wrote. The main point is that all information should be in the question. This site is used as a knowledge base for people having similar problems, so it is important that they can find your question and the corresponding answer. Without your confirmation that you use Notepad the answer was based on guessing.

Answer (score 6):

The problem isn’t your code. The problem is that [Notepad.exe<sup>1</sup> thinks that your file is UTF-16 encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts), when in reality it’s ASCII encoded. The file is fine.

---

<sup>1</sup> or whatever editor you’re opening the file in